# Generalized Random Forest / Causal Forest on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, package, random-forest

I was looking for the Generalized Random Forest / Causal Forest algorithm on Python, but found it only for R: https://github.com/grf-labs/grf

This algorithm cannot be obtained using the regular scikit-learn functions of Random Forest.

Is there any possible way that will help me to conduct Causal Forest or Generalized Random Forest on Python?

Comment: If https://causal-forest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html is what you wanted the documentation says it must be installed from source from the Github - the package is not in PyPI at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I'm not really sure how to install it with the Github source, how should I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/timmens/causal-forest has a setup.py, so can use that to install with the usual procedure, or the README says it can be installed with conda if you use that. But you might have tried the conda and it didn't work.

Comment: you could also check out uber's causal ml - https://github.com/uber/causalml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I eventually found the correct answer for that question!

There is a great package by microsoft for Python called "EconML".

It contains several functions for generalized random forests and causal forests.

It is absolutely great for those who need some causal inference functions:

https://econml.azurewebsites.net/

https://github.com/microsoft/EconML

Just apply: `pip install econml` and things will become really organized and easy :)